# Groovy : how to group map values by 2 different criteria?

Tags: groovy, group-by, maps

How can I group map values by 2 different criteria to get the outputs below ?

```
def listOfMaps = [
  [name:'Clark', city:'London', hobby: 'chess'], [name:'Sharma', city:'London', hobby: 'design'],
  [name:'Maradona', city:'LA', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Zhang', city:'HK', hobby: 'chess'],
  [name:'Ali', city: 'HK', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Liu', city:'HK', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Doe', city:'LA', hobby: 'design'], [name:'Smith', city:'London', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Johnson', city: 'London', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Waters', city:'LA', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Hammond', city:'LA', hobby: 'design'], [name:'Rogers', city:'LA', hobby: 'chess'],
]
```

1. group order : hobby, city

   ```
   poker
       London
           Smith
           Johnson
       LA
           Maradona
           Waters
       HK
           Ali
           Liu
   design
       London
           Sharma
       LA
           Doe
           Hammond
       HK
   chess
       London
           Clark   
       LA
           Rogers
       HK
           Zhang
   ```
2. group order : city, hobby

   ```
   London
       poker
           Smith
           Johnson
       design
           Sharma
       chess
           Clark
   LA
       poker
           Maradona
           Waters
       design
           Doe
           Hammond
       chess
           Rogers

   HK
       poker
           Ali
           Liu
       design
       chess
           Zhang
   ```

**Edit :**

What I really need is the way to iterate to effectively loop through the group structure, and be able to construct the result (group / subgroup / name ).

Something like :

1. for each group, print/output the group name;
2. for each subgroup inside a group, print/output the subgroup name
3. inside each subgroup, print the names.

It would yield the result outlined above.

As a nice aside, I would like to sort the whole data structure (groups and names).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the first case:

```
result = map.groupBy( { it.hobby }, { it.city } )
```

and for the second:

```
result = map.groupBy( { it.city }, { it.hobby } )
```

You will end up with the original values in the map rather than just the name, but you will be able to do:

```
result[ 'poker' ][ 'HK' ].name
```

to get the result

```
["Ali", "Liu"]
```

btw:  This [form of `groupBy`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#groupBy%28java.lang.Object%29) has only been available since Groovy 1.8.1, so if you're stuck on an earlier version, this won't work

#### edit 2

Based on your comment below, you can then do:

```
result.each { a, b ->
  println "$a"
  b.each { c, d ->
    println "  $c"
    d.each {
      println "    $it.name"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the same logic as GVdP had in his answer, but I feel using the groupBy with multiple parameters like I have here makes your code more readable and obvious as to its intent

Comment: Thanks for your answers; it looks so simple once i see it :) I have a slight preference for tim_yates answer, which seems even more intuitive. Thank you again !

Comment: I added a sort criteria (using another tim_yates idea) : `result = map.sort{ a, b -> a.city <=> b.city ?: a.hobby <=> b.hobby }.groupBy( { it.city }, { it.hobby } ) ` but don't know where to include a sort on the name

Comment: ok, found it : result = map.sort{ a, b -> a.city <=> b.city ?: a.hobby <=> b.hobby ?: a.name <=> b.name}.groupBy( { it.city }, { it.hobby } )

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result to be a couple of nested maps, try something like this:

```
def byHobbyCity = map.groupBy{it.hobby}.collectEntries{k, v -> [k, v.groupBy{it.city}]}
def byCityHobby = map.groupBy{it.city}.collectEntries{k, v -> [k, v.groupBy{it.hobby}]}

println byHobbyCity['chess']['London']*.name
==> [Clark]

println byCityHobby['London']['chess']*.name
==> [Clark]
```

Comment: OK, I like both answers, but what I really need is the way to iterate to effectively loop through the group structure, and be able to construct the result (group / subgroup / name )

Comment: OK, I like both answers, but what I really need is the way to iterate to effectively loop through the group structure, and be able to construct the result (group / subgroup / name ) . Something like : 1. for each group, print/output the group name; 2. for each subgroup inside a group, print/output the subgroup name 3. inside each subgroup, print the names. It would yield the result outlined in the OP. I tried building on ataylor's structure proposal but couldn't get to anything useful; neither do I see how to implement the looping structure with tim_yates solution.

Comment: @Michel added another edit to my answer. This really should go in the question though, rather than down here where it may be missed...

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on your comments, this will do as you ask:

```
def listOfMaps = [
  [name:'Clark', city:'London', hobby: 'chess'], [name:'Sharma', city:'London', hobby: 'design'],
  [name:'Maradona', city:'LA', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Zhang', city:'HK', hobby: 'chess'],
  [name:'Ali', city: 'HK', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Liu', city:'HK', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Doe', city:'LA', hobby: 'design'], [name:'Smith', city:'London', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Johnson', city: 'London', hobby: 'poker'], [name:'Waters', city:'LA', hobby: 'poker'],
  [name:'Hammond', city:'LA', hobby: 'design'], [name:'Rogers', city:'LA', hobby: 'chess'],
]

listOfMaps.groupBy {it.hobby}.each { k,v ->
 println k
 v.groupBy {it.city}.each {k1, v1->
  println "  $k1"
  v1.each {
   println "    $it.name"
  }
 }
}
```

Tested with Groovy 1.7.10